# ¿Deberíamos abrir la puerta a agrupar otros idiomas en este stack?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ámbito, idioma-de-la-publicación

Sé que me voy a meter en el mayor [berenjenal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5NIOz0T) del mundo haciendo esta pregunta, pero allá voy. Todo comienza con la pregunta [Catalan word for the Spanish language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19788/12637), que ha sido cerrada (y con razón) por no ser una pregunta sobre el idioma español, sino sobre el catalán.

Hay muchos idiomas con un número de hablantes relativamente pequeño si los comparamos con el español, que se hablan en lugares donde el español es idioma oficial. Solo en España tenemos unos cuantos, sin contar los que pueda haber en Hispanoamérica y que desconozco.

La cuestión es: para hacer preguntas sobre estos idiomas en Stack Exchange, ¿se deberían crear stacks independientes para cada uno de los idiomas, o la unión hace la fuerza? Tal y como yo lo veo, sería como si en Stack Overflow se obligara a preguntar en un stack diferente las preguntas sobre C#, o sobre Java, o sobre Python, etc. No, todas se hacen en el mismo.

Por tanto, ¿sería posible permitir que las preguntas sobre el gallego, catalán, euskera, asturiano, y cualquier otra lengua cooficial que conviva con el español en cualquier país se preguntaran también aquí? Esto implicaría crear etiquetas específicas para los idiomas (lo que nos vendría bien, ya que tenemos pocas etiquetas en comparación con otros sitios), aumentar el público del sitio, ampliar las posibles preguntas y, en definitiva, tener más posibilidades de salir de beta. Esto podría implicar incluso algo que no sé si se permite o no, que sería la posibilidad de cambiar el nombre del stack de "Spanish" a otro término que recoja y aglutine a todos estos idiomas.

¿Creéis posible un stack así? ¿O preferís que cada idioma se las apañe como pueda?

Comment: Qué pregunta tan apropiada. El proceso habitual es proponer un sitio en Area51 e ir hirviéndolo poco a poco hasta que se gradúe. La sección de [Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture) tiene muchas propuestas de idiomas, pero si el [lenguas eslavas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102374/slavic-languages) lo tiene peludo, o incluso nosotros en [spanish.se] estamos lejos de graduarnos, mucho más lo tendrían el catalán, gallego o vasco. No veo petición de sitio para lenguas románicas, que probablemente resolvería el tema.

Comment: Lo que sí leo es el debate en [What are the advantages of single language sites over collective ones?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/22947/76013), donde parece que "ganó" la tesis de no mezclar idiomas. Como catalanoparlante me da pena tener que cerrar preguntas como la que mencionas porque es "off-topic", además sin poder ofrecer un sitio adecuado donde plantearla. Veamos qué opina la gente.

Comment: @fedorqui precisamente ahí quería llegar: normalmente cuando cerramos preguntas porque consideramos que no pertenecen a este stack podemos dar una alternativa, y en ocasiones podemos hasta migrarla. No es el caso de la pregunta mencionada, que queda en una especie de limbo mientras no haya un stack de catalán.

Comment: Creo que las preguntas del tipo en que piensas suelen ser on-topic en Linguistics.  O por lo menos, hay un número de preguntas sobre otros idiomas del tipo que serían on-topic aquí si fuese de castellano.  Hubo un intento para idiomas surasiásticos (http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/565/announcing-proposed-se-site-for-southeast-asian-languages?rq=1) pero falló.  Quizás la idea podría ser repetida para los idiomas neolatinos con las preguntas de solo IT, ES, FR y PT off-topic, las demás de solo una lengua on-topic, y las comparativas on-topic.

Comment: Entiendo que el criterio sería "lengua cooficial", pero creo que el euskera tiene poca relación con otras lenguas romances como el castellano, catalán, etc. Cooficial o no, otros usuarios pedirán que se extienda el criterio para incluir otras lenguas que cohabitan en su países, como el **mapuche**, sobre el que incluso tenemos [alguna pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10344/5481).

Comment: Dudo que esto tenga mucho recorrido, ni siquera a provocado mucho debate pero me pregunto: ¿Por qué tienen que ser lenguas oficiales? Que un idioma no tenga el estatus de "oficial" no lo hace menos idioma o menos interesante. Por otra parte admitir solamente lenguas romances lingüisticamente tendría sentido pero dejariamos fuera todas las lenguas americanas y el euskera que también han contribuido al desarrollo del castellano. Creo que todos esos idiomas lo tendrían complicado para crear su propio stack, algunos casi imposible pero tampoco sabría decir si tienen cabida en este.

Answer (score 3):

## Otros Stacks

A mi me gustaría mucho que este stack se abriera a [los otros idiomas de España](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiomas_de_Espa%C3%B1a). Hay precedentes:

- **SE Chinese** incluye [**tibetano**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tibetan) y [**todas las lenguas chinas**](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/translation-from-dialects-off-topic)
  (e.g. [**hokkien**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hokkien), [**hakka**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hakka), [**shanghainese**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shanghainese), [**cantonese**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantonese) etc además de mandarín)
- **SE Japanese** incluye [**ryukyuense**](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/944/are-questions-on-okinawan-or-other-ryukyuan-languages-on-topic) y [**ainu**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ainu)
- **SE Ukranian** incluye [**rusyn**](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113/are-questions-about-the-rusyn-language-stuff-accepted-here)
- **SE German** incluye [**yidis**](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/is-yiddish-on-topic)
- **SE English** incluye [**escocés**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/should-scots-language-questions-be-considered-in-the-english-language-community)
- **SE Korean** incluye [**jeju**](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/482/what-dialectal-language-can-i-expect-in-jeju-do)
- **SE Latin** incluye [**griego**](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions)

Y hay más sitios en que hay algún soporte propuesto, pero no consenso, para otros idiomas:

- **SE Portugués** y [**gallego**](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/are-questions-about-mirand%C3%AAs-on-topic/294#294) y mirandés
- **SE Italian** y los otros [**idiomas italianos**](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/129/4183)

A diferencia de estos, **SE French** y **SE Russian** no incluyen preguntas sobre [lenguas minoritarias](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/are-minority-languages-on-topic-les-langues-r%c3%a9gionales-sont-elles-dans-le-sujet) (e.j. provenzal, [bielorruso](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/including-other-other-slavic-languages-to-grow-site)).

## Opciones

Dado estas normas, hay multiples opciones que se presentan. Además del castellano (y sus variedades internacionales), permitir preguntas sobre los siguientes grupos de lenguas:

1. los idiomas descendidos de castellano
   <sup>*ladino, español amazónico, lenguas criollas de base española (chavacano etc.)*</sup>
2. los otros idiomas romances de España
   <sup>*gallego, astur-leonés, aragonés, catalán, aranés*</sup>
3. vasco

## Opiniones

Creo que 1. no es muy controvertido, dada la muy íntima relación entre las lenguas (mucha gente las considera como variedades de español), y que ya admitimos preguntas sobre [portuñol y frespañol](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/questions-about-portu%C3%B1ol-or-frespa%C3%B1ol) y castellano antiguo y medieval.

---

<sup>**Datos:** los idiomas hablados en casa: Spanish (81%) | Catalan (8%) | Valencian (4%) | Galician (3%) | Basque (1%)</sup>
<sup>- [Pew Research Center, Spring 2019 Global Attitudes Survey](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2020/01/06/speaking-the-national-language-at-home-is-less-common-in-some-european-countries/)</sup>

Comment: Esa fue mi idea principal, pero claro, el español no es un idioma solo de España, sino de muchos otros países que también tienen sus lenguas cooficiales. Habría que hacer una lista exhaustiva y saber dónde poner el límite.

Comment: If we do this I think we should restrict the questions to being about the other languages but still insist that they be asked and answered in Spanish or English. I would restrict the list to Romance languages and not allow Basque or the many languages of Central and South America.

Comment: Nótese que idioma != dialecto, y dialecto es lo que se acepta en distintos ejemplos que proporcionas. Catalán, vasco y gallego (así como otros idiomas de España) no son dialectos del castellano, por lo que bajo el paraguas de Spanish.SE no veo lógico ni coherente que se agrupen. Si existiera un sitio genérico sobre lenguas romances, sí, pero no en este caso.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' en cuales ejemplos? Yiddish sí desciende de High German, pero la comunidad lingüística lo considere un idioma distinto (como ladino/castellano, o gallego/portugués). Rusyn es un caso más político - algunos lingüistas sí, otros no - pero la comunidad lingüística considera todos los otros ejemplos citados distintas lenguas, incluso los que se suele llamar 'dialectos' vulgarmente (como las otras lenguas de China e Italia): https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/810/ https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25621/

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' `"no son dialectos del castellano, por lo que bajo el paraguas de Spanish.SE no veo lógico ni coherente que se agrupen."` yo también preferiría un stack genérico de "Languages" o "Minority languages" o algo así creado explícitamente para las lenguas sin apoyo suficiente para su propio sitio, pero dado que otros stacks permiten preguntas sobre otras lenguas geográficamente relacionados (genéticamente sí - como japonés/okinawan - o no - como japonés/ainu), quería discutir la idea.

Comment: Revisando con detalle las respuestas que enlazas, veo que Portuguese.SE _no_ tiene preguntas sobre gallego. La respuesta del mod tchrist va en ese sentido y de hecho la etiqueta [galego] que mencionan actualmente está vacía de preguntas. El caso italiano es algo diferente, pues se engloba en italiano un montón de dialectos e incluso lenguas mutuamente poco comprensibles. Pero a efectos de esta pregunta, allí hablan de dialectos, no de idiomas.

Comment: Mi punto aquí es que el país en el que hablan no debe utilizarse como argumento para agruparlo en un sitio u otro. El catalán es mas similar al italiano que al castellano e igual de similar al francés y portugués (fuente: [Lexical similarity in Indo-European languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_similarity#Indo-European_languages).

Comment: Una lengua es un dialecto con un ejército y una marina https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Una_lengua_es_un_dialecto_con_un_ej%C3%A9rcito_y_una_marina

Comment: Although I would broadly support this suggestion I am not sure we would miss much if we did not do it. It does seem a shame that Catalan with such  large number of speakers does not have a place anywhere in the Stack.

Comment: Disculpa por hacerte perder un trozo de edición, empecé a corregir y no vi que habías editado

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' no te preocupes - gracias para la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Mi muy personal opinion es q en este caso, la union no necesariamente hace la fuerza. El tráfico es relativamente modesto, y afortunadamente la mayoria aqui somos bilingües, sin embargo; las [estadísticas de area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) hablan de varias areas en las que hay que trabajar.

poniendome en los zapatos de alguien que no habla ingles, le puede resultar confuso ver casi la mitad del contenido en ese idioma, creo q es una de las razones de la baja participación. abrir la puerta a dos o tres idiomas mas, se podría diluir mas la participación sobre todo en castellano.

hace unos días participé en English language, y me sorprendió que cada respuesta es un debate en sus comentarios! en el resto del mundo de alguna forma no les intimida nada y aunque sean opiniones personales la participación llueve y bien que mal los moderadores orientan a los nuevos y así la comunidad crece.

A reserva de un analisis respaldado en BigDdata con analitica del sitio u no menos de 2 gráficas en R, intuyo q mas lenguajes != mas tráfico/participación.